# Laurent series about infinity and essential singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am having some confusion about Laurent series at infinity and essential singularities. Consider the function:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
which has a Laurent Series about infinity of:
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}-...$$
From this it would appear that $f(z)$ would have an essential singularity. However,
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{t-1}$$
Where $t=1/z$ does not have an essential singularity at $t=0$ which would mean that $f(z)$ does not have an essential singularity at $z=\infty$. Which of my reasonings is right and why is the other wrong?

Comment: You mix up $t=0$ (i.e. $z=\infty$) and $z=0$. They are completely different points. Your Laurent series converges for $|z|>1$ where $z=0$ does not belong to, so the expansion is not valid around $z=0$.

Comment: @A.G. so $f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}-...$ is not the Laurent series about infinity?

Comment: It is. But what "around infinity" has to do with "near the zero"?

Comment: @A.G. Sorry I don't quite know why you are bringing zero into this? If $f(z)$ is the Laurent series about $\infty$ simply by the virtue that it has a non-terminating principal part, means it is a singularity?

Comment: When you say that $-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}-...$ has a principal part you mean implicitly that it is a Laurent series **at zero** (note that at infinity it is analytical, so no principal part). This is how $z=0$ comes to play. In general, "principal part = negative powers" works for finite numbers only. For infinity the correct way to define it is the substitution $t=1/z$ and reducing to the case of $t=0$.

Comment: @A.G. So just to clarify, if $z_0$ is finite and $f(z)$ has an infinite principal part about $z_0$ then $z_0$ is an essential singularity. If $z_0=\infty$ the Laurent series if given by that of $f(1/t)$ about $t=0$ with $t=\frac{1}{z}$. However, $\infty$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$ if this Laurent series has an infinite number of analytic terms  when written in $z$ or equivalently an infinite number of principal terms when written in $t$. If this is correct (?) I am happy to accept your comments in the form of an answer.